# About structure in C

Tags: c

I am confuse about a structure. Can you guys explain to me what is the meaning of this structure?

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8 event;
  uint8 status; 
}osal_event_hdr_t;
```

Then, the structure above is define again in another structure like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  osal_event_hdr_t hdr;
  uint8 state;
  uint8 keys;
}keyChange_t;
```

And the structure above declare in a function, what is the meaning of this
`keyChange_t *msgPtr`? Is the structure pointed to the `msgPtr` but`msgPtr` is `uint8`. Can you guys explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: What's your question? Is your question about what structures are? If it is, just read any [struct tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html). Alternatively you may be wondering what the `*` syntax is. Those are [pointers](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/16/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/).

Comment: Which part of the first structure don't you understand?  It looks like a very basic untagged structure type.  The type `uint8` isn't a standard type (as in, it is not part of Standard C, nor standard POSIX), but that shouldn't be too much of a problem.  Similarly, what's complicated about the second structure?     What makes you think `msgPtr` is `uint8`?

Comment: Then I'm sorry. This question isn't well researched at all, and isn't really appropriate for the website.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I am mistake for the msgPtr. It is not an `uint8` . I have a question in 2nd structure the `osal_event_hdr_t hdr` , is the first structure define in the 2nd structure and what is the hdr there?

Comment: One `struct` can have other `struct` member, like `uint8 state`, `hdr` is also a variable of type `struct osal_event_hdr_t`

Comment: I know that is a pointer . The `osal_event_hdr_t hdr` there confuse me, why the `hdr` is behind the `osal_event_hdr_t` ?

Comment: Yes; there's a copy of the first structure type embedded in the second structure, as element `.hdr`.  You can access the `.event` member of the embedded structure using `msgPtr->hdr.event`, for example, assuming `msgPtr` is properly initialized.  The notation `osal_event_hdr_t hdr;` is exactly parallel to `int member;` except the type is `osal_event_hdr_t` instead of `int` and the member name is `hdr` instead of `member`.

Comment: Ah thanks Jonathan, I am getting clear now.

Comment: the `keyChange_t *msgPtr` means the structure is pointed to `msgPtr` ?

Comment: It means that `msgPtr` holds a pointer to a `keyChange_t` structure, yes; colloquially, it is a pointer to a `keyChange_t` structure.  If it is properly initialized, it will point to a `keyChange_t` structure that has been allocated somewhere, perhaps as a regular variable, perhaps via dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` or one of its friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first structure is a container type named osal_event_hdr_t which contains two variables which I assume are meant to be of type uint8_t. You can access their contents like so:

```
osal_event_hdr_t foo;
foo.event = 1;
foo.status = 2;
```

The second struct is a lot like the first, but it actually contains one of the first structs! So to access the first struct from this one would be like:

```
keyChange_t bar;
bar.hdr.status = 3;
```

I tried... lol

Comment: I think more or less is like this, thanks for your reply =)